# Any way to keep the internal common in macros?

Tags: c++, macros

For example, I have a simple macro

```
#define MIN(a, b)   (a) < (b) ? (a) : (b)
```

and I want to use

```
MIN(pow(2, 3) , 10);
```

The internal common gives trouble. I can do as following

```
int a = pow(2, 3);
MIN(a, 10);
```

I am looking for a better way that is more readable by like keeping `pow(2, 3)` in the macro? Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: I'd say "Don't use macros"

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::min` instead:

```
#include <algorithm>

//...
double x = std::min(pow(2, 3) , 10);
```

Generally, you should prefer an inline function over a macro. If the purpose of the macro is to allow it to work for a variety of types, you can use a template.

```
template <typename T>
inline T SomeFunction (T x, T y) {
    T result;
    //...do something with x and y and assign to result
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Could even make your own `min` as a function if you don't want to include `algorithm`.

Comment: @Rapptz: Right, I have expanded the answer.